# f# filtering out long list

Tags: module, f#

I'm currently taking calsses in F#, we have gotten the following assigment https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Hmy.png

And I'm currently just focusing on getting isEmpty to work, but it not that easy :D

I have tried to write the following in 'intLinked.fs':

```
module IntLinkedList

type intLinkedList = Nil | Cons of int * intLinkedList

//Check if a stack is empty

let isEmpty (stck: intLinkedList): bool = stck.IsEmpty
```

I'm certain that I have written my app.fsproj correct, but when I run the following debug message apears:

> error FS0039: The type 'intLinkedList' does not define the field,
> constructor or member 'IsEmpty'

**The code works when:**

I write the following in *intLinkedList.fsi*:

```
module IntLinkedList
type stack = int list
val isEmpty : stack -> bool
```

I write the following in *intLinkedList.fs*:

```
module IntLinkedList
type stack = int list
let isEmpty (stck: stack): bool = stck.IsEmpty
```

I write the following in *intLinkedApp.fsx*:

```
open IntLinkedList
let emptyList = []
isEmpty emptyList |> printfn " Empty list is empty : %A"
```

It's when I try to use the type intLinkedList I run into problems.
As far as I understand Nil is just an empty list [], but it doesn't seem to act like it.

Is it posible that any of you might be able to give me a hint, so I can get back on track?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your custom type doesn't implement `.IsEmpty`. That's what you're supposed to be doing for your assignment, writing a function that actually checks if your custom linked list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nil` is *not* "just an empty list". Your type `intLinkedList` is a completely new type, not related to F# built-in list at all.

It has *the same general structure* as F# built-in list. In smartypants talk you might say it's "isomorphic" to the F# built-in list. But it's not the same thing.

This means that you can't use methods and functions that work with F# built-in lists on your custom type. You have to implement them yourself.

For example, the `IsEmpty` property might be implemented something like:

```ml
type intLinkedList = Nil | Cons of int * intLinkedList
    with
        member this.IsEmpty = match this with Nil -> true | Cons _ -> false
```